# Is there any need to remove TextWatcher when dialog is dismissed in android?

Tags: android, dialog, android-textwatcher

**I want to listen to TextView text changes in my dialog, So
I am using TextWatcher like below:**

```
 final View layout = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_history,
                    container, false);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.full_screen_dialog);

            dialog.setContentView(layout);
            final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;
            if (window != null) {

              

                window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                layoutParams = window.getAttributes();
                if (layoutParams != null) {
                    layoutParams.windowAnimations = R.style.ChooserStyle;
                    layoutParams.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM;
                    window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
                }
            }


           


            TextView searchHistoryTV = layout.findViewById(R.id.searchHistoryTV);


            searchHistoryTV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    CharSequence editable = searchHistoryTV.getText();
                    //thereafter use this CharSequence

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });


            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
```

**Is there any need to remove TextWatcher when dialog is dismissed i.e. in dialog.setOnDismissListener()?Or what if I don't remove it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to remove any `listeners` specifically, once the `dialog` dismisses, all the child `view` instances inside it will be destroyed anyways. So nothing happens even if you do not remove `TextListener` as it is attached to `EditText` also gets destroyed `onDismiss`.